# The logcat in android shows simply shutting down the VM?

Tags: android, android-emulator, garbage-collection, stack-trace, android-logcat

Yesterday it worked perfectly, 
but today shows a message 
"unfortunately the app has stopped",
and the logcat shows "shutting down the VM".

Stack Trace of this app..

```
11-27 13:24:17.035: W/Trace(806): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-27 13:24:17.455: W/Trace(806): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-27 13:24:17.485: W/Trace(806): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-27 13:24:17.485: D/AndroidRuntime(806): Shutting down VM
11-27 12:30:51.683: D/AndroidRuntime(734): Shutting down VM
11-27 12:30:51.943: D/dalvikvm(734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 137K, 9% free 2625K/2880K,paused23ms+7ms, total 230ms
11-27 12:37:12.259: D/dalvikvm(878): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
11-27 12:37:12.259: D/AndroidRuntime(878): Shutting down VM
11-27 12:43:22.839: D/dalvikvm(939): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
11-27 12:43:22.878: D/AndroidRuntime(939): Shutting down VM
```

this is program..

```
package com.raghuram.simplecalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public abstract class CalculatorActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
        OnClickListener addlisten= new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    EditText tx1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText tx2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    EditText tx3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    Float res=Float.parseFloat(tx1.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(tx2.getText().toString());                  
                    tx3.setText(Float.toString(res));


                }
        };

        ImageButton a=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        a.setOnClickListener(addlisten);

        OnClickListener sublisten= new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    EditText tx1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText tx2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    EditText tx3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);                   
                    Float res1=Float.parseFloat(tx1.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(tx2.getText().toString());                 
                    tx3.setText(Float.toString(res1));

                }
        };

        ImageButton s=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        s.setOnClickListener(sublisten);

        OnClickListener mullisten= new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    EditText tx1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText tx2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    EditText tx3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);                   
                    Float res1=Float.parseFloat(tx1.getText().toString()) * Float.parseFloat(tx2.getText().toString());                 
                    tx3.setText(Float.toString(res1));

                }
        };

        ImageButton m=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        m.setOnClickListener(mullisten);

        OnClickListener divlisten= new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    EditText tx1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText tx2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    EditText tx3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    Float x=Float.parseFloat(tx2.getText().toString());

                        if(x>0)
                        {
                            Float res1=Float.parseFloat(tx1.getText().toString()) / Float.parseFloat(tx2.getText().toString());                 
                            tx3.setText(Float.toString(res1));
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Context context = getApplicationContext();
                            CharSequence text = "Invalid number.";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            toast.show();

                        }

                }




        };

        ImageButton d=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        d.setOnClickListener(divlisten);


        ImageButton e=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);        
        e.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                System.exit(0);
            }

        });

    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_calculator, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

It shows the exact results yesterday, but now it closed forcely..
how to manage the memory.

Comment: Please give more details and code.

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception from logcat.  It will be before the part you have shown.

Comment: just now edited the question, what ll be the problem.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `abstract` before your class name.

And true to stop your activity by calling `finish()` instead of `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: Don't you get a stacktrace?

Comment: I learned from net, that just double click the log cat line it ll show the stack trace lines in log cat window.

Comment: FWIW, Class.newInstance() will fail if the class to be instantiated is primitive (e.g. "int" or "float"), is an interface, is an array, or is abstract.  These four items are identified in the rather obscure "newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1" message, which in this case means "newInstance failed because it was asked to instantiate an abstract class".